# LibGDX polygon caching

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, game-mechanics, maps

I am developing an Android game using LibGDX and I have big world map made of polygons.

I use PolygonSprite and PolygonSpriteBatch, when I render map, I get 30-35fps and it feels laggy. I wonder if there is a way to cache polygons like sprites in SpriteCache and is it a good idea to cache part of the map which is currently on camera?